# iMacros selecting links in a class

Tags: macros, imacros

These are the links I want to select and open in a new tab.

```
<div class="text-right" style="border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 255);"><a href="http://thisisaurl.com/klw4azh.html">Fine</a></div>
```

There are multiple links I want to select and the urls are all diffrent. I can highlight the div that has the links in it but I can never actually select the link and open it in a new tab. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
tag pos=1 type=a attr=href:http://thisisaurl.com/* extract=href
tab open
tab t=2
url goto={{!extract}}
```

this will scrape 1st link and open it in new tab, if you need second link just change pos index